# How to prevent multidocument form page from reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working on a web app that takes the user through multiple forms with simple interface of a 'back' button, form, 'save' button and a 'next' button.
Clicking 'save' only calculates a number from given answers and sends it to localStorage.
When I then click 'next', it opens the next html file I prepared, constructed the same way, just with a different form. The problem is that if I press 'back', the form on the first page is empty, but when I use the browser's 'back' button, it's all there. How do I get this result with my 'back' and 'next' buttons? I'd like the user to be able to browse their answers as well as see a certain form already completed if they encounter it on a different path (there are various paths through 3 to 5 of 11 forms created, depending on what the user wants to calculate).

I understand it's opening the html file every time I click an 'a href', but I don't know how to change it. I tried searching for html form reloading prevention etc. but it doesn't seem to yield any answers. I'm not sure I know how to formulate my problem in a simple enough way.

Answer (score 3):

Best simple solution would pretty much be what "Manolo" suggested.

1. Put all the forms you need in one HTML doc
2. Set all the form's style to "display: none" except the first
3. Create a simple JS function that changes the "display" style accordingly and attach it with the "onclick" attribute to your buttons.

Sorry for the lack of code. Typed this on mobile and hoped it would be straight forward enough. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [History_API of DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API) to manipulate the history

```
let stateObj = { foo: "bar" }
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html")
```

And can catch thee event of back and next button of navigator with
[WindowEventHandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

Answer (score 1):

Load the forms as you need them using javascript to request them to your server. Use fetch api.

Other solution is to add all the forms to one page and hidde them all from the user. When the user click next you hide firstForm and show secondForm.